# Why some properties are hidden from Object Inspector when more than one item is selected?

Tags: delphi, properties, components, design-time, object-inspector

I've noticed that some properties disappear from the *Object Inspector* when selecting more than one item.

Why does this happen and how to control this behavior when creating a component?

**Example:**

Add 2 buttons (`TButton`) to a form and select one of them.

[image]

In the *Object Inspector* you can see all `TButton`'s published properties (Note that there's also the `Constraints` property).

[image]

Add the other button to the current selection (Click while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> key).

[image]

As you can see, some properties have been hidden from *Object Inspector* (Note that the `Constraints` is no more visible).

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whether a property is displayed when multiple objects are selected is controlled by the *property editor* configured for that property. Property editors (descended from `TPropertyEditor` in *DesignEditors.pas*) have a `GetAttributes` method that returns a set of attributes that apply to the editor. If the set includes `paMultiSelect`, then the property will be displayed.

Given that the property value is displayed as the constraint values, rather than just *(TSizeConstraints)*, I conclude that that property is not using the generic `TClassProperty` editor. That editor sets `paMultiSelect`, but based on your pictures, the property editor to `TSizeConstraints` doesn't. It was probably an oversight.

You could try registering your own property editor. Find the property editor currently registered for `TSizeConstraints` (by searching the source code for *TSizeConstraints*, for instance) and, in a design-time package, declare a new class descended from that one. Override `GetAttributes` to return the value you need. Finally, follow examples elsewhere in the code to call `RegisterPropertyEditor`.